# Label ACF 'repeater' doesn't work anymore since update WordPress and ACF plugin

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have updated my `WordPress` from 4.6.x to 5.2.1.
I have also updated plugin `ACF Pro` from 4.x.x to 5.8.1.

Since then, `ACF` labels of type 'repeater' doesn't work anymore :
they don't appear anymore in admin panel and in front of application.
The other labels work well.

I don't know why. Do you have an idea ?

```
{
                "key": "field_56f04b4f1d998",
                "label": "Layouts",
                "name": "layouts",
                "type": "repeater",
                "instructions": "",
                "required": 0,
                "conditional_logic": [],
                "wrapper": {
                    "width": "",
                    "class": "",
                    "id": ""
                },
                "collapsed": "",
                "min": "",
                "max": "",
                "layout": "block",
                "button_label": "Add layout",
                "sub_fields": [
                    {
                        "key": "field_573c2f5d67d89",
                        "label": "Type",
                        "name": "type",
                        "type": "select",
                        "instructions": "",
                        "required": 1,
                        "conditional_logic": 0,
                        "wrapper": {
                            "width": "",
                            "class": "",
                            "id": ""
                        },
                        "choices": {
                            "layout100": "1\/1",
                            "layout100_full": "1\/1 full",
                            "layout5050": "1\/2 + 1\/2",
                            "layout3366": "1\/3 + 2\/3",
                            "layout6633": "2\/3 + 1\/3"
                        },
                        "default_value": [
                            0
                        ],
                        "allow_null": 0,
                        "multiple": 0,
                        "ui": 0,
                        "ajax": 0,
                        "return_format": "value",
                        "placeholder": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "field_5a266ce145c75",
                        "label": "Border top ?",
                        "name": "border_top",
                        "type": "true_false",
                        "instructions": "",
                        "required": 0,
                        "conditional_logic": 0,
                        "wrapper": {
                            "width": "",
                            "class": "",
                            "id": ""
                        },
                        "message": "",
                        "default_value": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Comment: Did you try and reach out to ACF support or use their support forum? That's where I would start.

Answer (score 0):

Update acf-component-field plugin and add 'field_group_key=component_group_id' in your json.